Android TextToSpeech Api is not speaking on Meta Quest 3 VR
I'm encountering an issue with playing the Text-to-Speech (TTS) function on the Meta Quest 3 VR headset. The code snippet provided below initializes the TextToSpeech object in the onCreate method:
buttonSpeak.setOnClickListener {
    speak()
}
tts = TextToSpeech(this) { status ->
    if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH)
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error occurred: $status")
    }
}

meanwhile the speak function be like:

    private fun speak() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            tts.speak("Hi. I can speak.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null)
        } else {
            tts.speak("Hi, I can speak", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null)
        }
    }

However, upon execution, I consistently receive a TextToSpeech.ERROR status during the initialization process. Surprisingly, the same code works perfectly fine when executed on an Android phone.
The problematic behavior seems to be specific to the Meta Quest 3 VR headset, as it works as expected on other Android devices.
Could anyone please provide insights into why this issue might be occurring and suggest potential solutions or workarounds to enable Offline Text-to-Speech functionality on the Meta Quest 3  or other VR headset?

Try https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/hiai-Guides/on-device-text-to-speech-sdk-0000001059239344 and other ml kit based standalone text to speech solutions.
